# Can not use jconsole to connect to JBoss eap7.1

Tags: jboss

I installed eap7.1 on RHEL73, everything works fine, but failed to use jconsole to connect server instance, I didn't find anything related with how to set jmx component on eap7.1, but found something for eap6, here is main points I found:

1. Should disable management binding and enable an remote binding:
2. Add option as eap server startup option:
   -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl
   -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver
3. Use $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh to startup jconsole

But I always failed with jconsole reponse as " the connection to service:jmx:remote://192.168.56.11:4447 did not succeed"

Here is key point of domain.xml

```
...
           <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
                <endpoint/>
                <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </subsystem>

...
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
                <expose-resolved-model/>
                <expose-expression-model/>
                <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
            </subsystem>
...
        <socket-binding-group name="ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
            ...
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            ...
        </socket-binding-group>
```

server startup successfully with the following log

```
"INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 192.168.56.11:4447"
```

netstat -an shows 4447 is ready.

The following is some guides on eap6 I followed:

```
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/149973
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/443033
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/413283
https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/JMX_Access_to_Domain_Mode_EAP_7_Server_Node(this is for eap7)
```

Is there anything special on JMX for eap7.1?

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems as you. My quick fix is:

**change this:**

```
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" **security-realm="ApplicationRealm"**/>
```

**to this:**

`<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>`

**or remove realm:**

```
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting"/>
```

Probably I have a wrong user in ApplicationRealm or don't have the permission. I use this in zabbix jmx monitoring in domain mode with wildfly 10, 10.1 and 11.

Comment: BTW, I have to copy mgmt-* from DC to HC  which has server runs jmx, but coping application-* from DC to HC does make  <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" **security-realm="ApplicationRealm"**/> worked for opening jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the jconsole to EAP 7.1 with default configuration using the management realm. You just have to:

1. add a management user, via `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh`
2. start EAP
3. connect to jmx service address
   `service:jmx:remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990` via
   `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh` using credentials defined in above step

n.b.: The protokoll may differ from previous versions of eap